# Is it always possible to split a complex function into the sum of its real + imaginary parts?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm looking for any kind of proof or at least an intuitive explanation. I am curious because I want to know:

if I have an unknown complex function that I want to manipulate, can I assume it has the structure `a(x) + ib(x)`.

It seems to me this should definitely be possible. I'm hoping someone can provide a lucid argument that makes the answer seem stupidly obvious

Comment: What situation/context let you to ask this question?  Was it assigned to you?  Are you curious? If curious, what led to the question? (What motivated you to ask this question?)

Comment: I've added more context/explanation, can you take me off hold?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new to math.SE, I recommend reading [here](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), [here](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ), [here](/help/notation), and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can.  The real and imaginary parts of a complex number uniquely determine it.  You can identify $\mathbb{C}$ with the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ via $a + ib \mapsto (a,b)$.

Let $X$ be a set, and let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $\pi_1: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $\pi(a,b) = a$, and let $\pi_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $\pi_2(a,b) = b$.

Let $u: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the composition $\pi_1 \circ f$, and let $v: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the composition $\pi_2 \circ f$.  Then obviously

$$f(x) = (u(x),v(x))$$

for any $x \in X$.  Or in the usual notation of complex numbers,

$$f(x) = u(x) + i v(x)$$

for all $x \in X$.  This is written more succinctly as $f = u + iv$.

Comment: To the downvoter, did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but it's one of the most cogent answer/"proof" here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Any complex number $z$ is of the form $x+iy$, where
$$x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2} \quad\text{and}\quad
  y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}
$$ are real numbers called the real and imaginary parts of $z$, respectively. If $f:A\to\mathbb{C}$ is a function from a set into the complex numbers, then define functions $u,v:A\to\mathbb{C}$ by
$$u(a)=\frac{f(a)+\overline{f(a)}}{2} \quad\text{and}\quad
  v(a)=\frac{f(a)-\overline{f(a)}}{2i}.
$$
Then $f(a)=u(a)+iv(a)$ for every $a\in A$, and as one would expect, we call $u$ the real part of $f$ and $v$ the imaginary part of $f$.

Comment: Dang. Beat me by seconds. $+1$ You need to divide by $i$ in the definition of $v$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Should $u,v : A \rightarrow R$ instead of $u,v : A \rightarrow C$

Comment: apologies, this is probably a stupid question, but for $\bar{f(a)}$, this is the complex conugate of the function $f(a)$, and not the complex conjugate as well as substituing $\bar(a)$ for $a$. E.g say if I wanted to use $v(a)=\frac{f(a)-\bar{f(a)}}{2i}$ to find the derivatives of the imaginary part of $f(a)$ w.r.t $a$ and $\bar{a}$, is there a way to get a more explicit expression on the $\bar{f(a)}$ term. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Any complex number $z$ can be written in the form $re^{i\theta}$...